# Install AutoIt Library for Robot Framework - Win 10

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I am trying to install the autoIt library to use it with robotFramework, but I keep encoutering this error:

```
Don't think we need to unregister the old one...
    %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\xxx xxx\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 70, in <module>
        subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 504, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\xxx xxx\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I have tried all the solution found so far on stackoverflow:

- Run cmd as Administrator
- Set HOMEDRIVE environment variable
- Manually run this command %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C 
  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll (which throw no 
  error)
- Using a fixed setup 
  py script :https://github.com/qitaos/robotframeworkautoitlibrary/issues/30
  ( which trhow this error :`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python "C:\xxx xxx\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py" "C:\xxx xxx\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll"' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Does anyone have others solutions ?
(If not I will go for SikuliX, even if AutoIt is the best for Win automation)

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried putting the AutoIt library in a directory that does not include spaces?  Probably not what's wrong, but possibly worth a try...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I just tried and it still throw: Command 'python "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py" "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll"' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: I figured it wouldn't work, but I occasionally run into places where the command parser interprets spaces as separate commands, and thought you might get lucky in this case.  Sorry - I have no other thoughts. :(

Comment: Yes, it could have work, thanks ! Hopefully I will find the solution at some point...